# How to use fibers with ruby eventmachine in non-rack?

Tags: ruby, httprequest, nonblocking, eventmachine, fibers

So basically my goal is get some sort of light-weight ruby daemon(or sidekiq/resque worker), that processes jobs and notifies other apps over http. The app itself does not need to receive http requests, so no rack to remain as light-weight as possible. Pretty much a bit of ruby code I can run in *loop {}*

So trying to not use EventMachine' reactor pattern and using fiber approach instead. Where would I put EM.run or EM.stop in this context *Thread.new { EM.run }* doesn't seem to be fiber aware so adding it gave no callbacks? Is there a [em-synchrony](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-synchrony) alternative to this?

```
#slow=true injects a sleep 3, so page 2 callback should output faster
require 'em-http-request'
require 'fiber'
def http_get(url)
  f = Fiber.current
  http = EventMachine::HttpRequest.new(url).get

  # resume fiber once http call is done
  http.callback { f.resume(http) }
  http.errback  { f.resume(http) }

  return Fiber.yield
end

puts "fetching some data from database for request params"
EventMachine.run do
  Fiber.new{
    page = http_get('http://localhost:3000/status?slow=true')
    puts "notified external page it responded with: #{page.response_header.status}"
  }.resume
  Fiber.new{
    page = http_get('http://localhost:4000/status')
    puts "notified external page 2 it responded with: #{page.response_header.status}"
  }.resume
  puts "Finishised notification task"
end
puts "Moving on to next task as fast as possible"
```

Comment: EM uses reactor under the hood, there's no way you either can avoid or should use it, take it as given.

What exactly confuses you in the way your code works?

Comment: https://github.com/igrigorik/em-synchrony#fiber-aware-multi-interface-parallel-http-requests, but don't do it

Answer (score -2):

Avoid reinventing the wheel, use [EM::Synchrony](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-synchrony) or even better switch to [celluloid](https://github.com/celluloid/celluloid) or [celluloid-io](https://github.com/celluloid/celluloid-io) as EM seems to have fallen out of maintenance

Comment: Not reinvent existing functions is good advice, it's also good advice to stay clear of unmaintained gems when building a new project, it's also good advice to point the OP in the direction of libs which are currently used to tackle such problems.